# Iterating over a large file directory system in python, getting too many values to unpack

Tags: python, file, directory

I am iterating over a very large file and directory system in python. I'm starting in the base directory and I know that the the directory goes no more than 1 folder deep, past the base directory. I am trying to read out the second line of each file in the base_directories children folder, using code like this:

```
a_list = []
  for dir, files in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file in files:
      f=open(file, 'r')
      for line in f:
        #reads in the second line
        if line==1:
          a_list.append(line)
          break
      f.close()
```

But I get too many values to unpack specifically on this line "for dir, file in os.walk(base_directory)" Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be unpacking a 3-tuple

```
walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)
    Directory tree generator.

    For each directory in the directory tree rooted at top (including top
    itself, but excluding '.' and '..'), yields a 3-tuple

        dirpath, dirnames, filenames
```

eg.

```
for dir, dirnames, files in os.walk(base_directory):
```

Also, this won't work. `line` is a string for starters

```
  for line in f:
    #reads in the second line
    if line==1:
      a_list.append(line)
      break
```

You could change it to something like this

```
  for i, line in enumerate(f):
    #reads in the second line
    if i==1:
      a_list.append(line)
      break
```

But I think this is a simpler way

```
  import os
  a_list = []
  for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(base_directory):
    for file in files:
      with open(os.path.join(dirpath, file), 'r') as f:
        next(f)                 # skip the first line
        a_list.append(next(f))  # store the second line
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked. Sorry if it was an easy question but i'm pretty new to python.